# SSL error: point is not on curve with psycopg2 on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, ssl, heroku, psycopg2

I've been able to connect to my psql database on Heroku using Navicat and pgAdmin, but I want programatic access through psycopg2. I tried the following:

```
psycopg2.connect(host=“…”, user=“…”, password=“…”, database=“…”, port=5432, sslmode='require')
```

but I get the following error:

sycopg2.OperationalError: SSL error: point is not on curve. This is a DB error but I don't know what it means nor how to solve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was a problem with the SSL libraries on Mac OS X. On my production Ubuntu it worked ok.